# Minimum cost solution to connect all elements in set A to at least one element in set B

Tags: swift, algorithm, graph-theory

I need to find the shortest set of paths to connect each element of Set A with at least one element of Set B. Repetitions in A OR B are allowed (but not both), and no element can be left unconnected. Something like this:

[image]

I'm representing the elements as integers, so the "cost" of a connection is just the absolute value of the difference. I also have a cost for crossing paths, so if Set A = [60, 64] and Set B = [63, 67], then (60 -> 67) incurs an additional cost. There can be any number of elements in either set.

I've calculated the table of transitions and costs (distances and crossings), but I can't find the algorithm to find the lowest-cost solution. I keep ending up with either too many connections (i.e., repetitions in *both* A and B) or greedy solutions that omit elements (e.g., when A and B are non-overlapping). I haven't been able to find examples of precisely this kind of problem online, so I hoped someone here might be able to help, or at least point me in the right direction. I'm not a graph theorist (obviously!), and I'm writing in Swift, so code examples in Swift (or pseudocode) would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: The solution offered by @Daniel is almost working, but it does occasionally add unnecessary duplicates. I *think* this may be something to do with the sorting of the priorityQueue -- the duplicates always involve identical elements with identical costs. My first thought was to add some kind of "positional encoding" (yes, Transformer-speak) to the costs, so that the costs are offset by their positions (though of course, this doesn't guarantee unique costs). I thought I'd post my Swift version here, in case anyone has any ideas:

```
public static func voiceLeading(from chA: [Int], to chB: [Int]) -> Set<[Int]> {
        var result: Set<[Int]> = Set()
        let im = intervalMatrix(chA, chB: chB)
        if im.count == 0 { return [[0]] }
        let vc = voiceCrossingCostsMatrix(chA, chB: chB, cost: 4)
        // NOTE: cm contains the weights
        let cm = VectorUtils.absoluteAddMatrix(im, toMatrix: vc)

        var A_links: [Int:Int] = [:]
        var B_links: [Int:Int] = [:]
        var priorityQueue: [Entry] = []
        for (i, a) in chA.enumerated() {
            for (j, b) in chB.enumerated() {
                priorityQueue.append(Entry(a: a, b: b, cost: cm[i][j]))
                if A_links[a] != nil {
                    A_links[a]! += 1
                } else {
                    A_links[a] = 1
                }
                if B_links[b] != nil {
                    B_links[b]! += 1
                } else {
                    B_links[b] = 1
                }
            }
        }
        priorityQueue.sort { $0.cost > $1.cost }
        while priorityQueue.count > 0 {
            let entry = priorityQueue[0]
            if A_links[entry.a]! > 1 && B_links[entry.b]! > 1 {
                A_links[entry.a]! -= 1
                B_links[entry.b]! -= 1
            } else {
                result.insert([entry.a, (entry.b - entry.a)])
            }
            priorityQueue.remove(at: 0)
        }
        
        return result
    }
```

Of course, since the duplicates have identical scores, it shouldn't be a problem to just remove the extras, but it feels a bit hackish...

UPDATE 2: Slightly less hackish (but still a bit!); since the requirement is that my result should have equal cardinality to `max(|A|, |B|)`, I can actually just stop adding entries to my `result` when I've reached the target cardinality. Seems okay...

UPDATE 3: Resurrecting this old question, I've recently had some problems arise from the fact that the above algorithm doesn't fulfill my requirement `|S| == max(|A|, |B|)` (where S is the set of pairings). If anyone knows of a simple way of ensuring this it would be much appreciated. (I'll obviously be poking away at possible changes.)

Comment: computerscience.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this. They won't be able to give concrete Swift implementations, but at least a general outline of an algorithm.

Comment: I think this problem is "minimum weighted bipartite matching" (although searching for " maximum weighted bipartite matching" would also be relevant, it's just the opposite)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll do a search for that. Sorry, but do you know if I can move the question to stackexchange in its current form—link it, or something? (I mean, is there a "built-in" solution here for doing that?)

Comment: You can close and migrate it, but only to `meta.stackoverflow.com`, `superuser.com`, `tex.stackexchange.com`,  `dba.stackexchange.com`, and `stats.stackexchange.com`. Which is weird, because those aren't even the most likely sites to need to migrate SO questions to. (Tex, really?). So no, I'm afraid you'll need to copy/paste your question content :/

Comment: Ha, okay, no worries. I've already found some promising and clearly relevant info on  bipartite matching, so I'll be able to make some headway now, thanks. Since I did say "point me in the right direction", if you want to post your suggestion as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. I often find that knowing what to search for is more-than-half the battle.

Comment: A lot of your code could be cleaned up if you use `subscript(_:default:)`, like `A_links[a, default: 0] += 1`

Comment: Ah, coolness—wasn't aware of that syntactic sugar. I have to admit, I haven't keep up with Swift's many changes particularly well. Also, I'm going to keep an eye on how my code above is working in practice. If things get wobbly I'll probably try something like to Hungarian matching.

Comment: It's not syntactic sugar, as in, it's not a special form baked into the languae. It' s just a regular method implemented in the standard library.

Comment: Really? I don't remember noticing that approach to defaults with Dictionaries (I came from Obj-C land, and probably didn't pay a lot of attention to the details)... but fair enough.

Comment: [Yup.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e9d4687e31a3ae8e90604d3b15bf8b241479c211/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L884-L904) Although the implementation does use some non-public features, for performance improvement. A blind "read, modify, write" operation causes an extraneous CoW copy (since at one point, the value will be referenced both by the dict, and the local reference you're modifying it through), which they get around using the hidden `_modify` declaration (instead of `set`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy task:

- Add all edges of the graph in a `priority_queue`, where the biggest priority is the edge with the biggest weight.
- Look each edge `e = (u, v, w)` in the `priority_queue`, where `u` is in **A**, `v` is in **B** and `w` is the weight.
- If removing `e` from the graph doesn't leave `u` or `v` isolated, remove it.
- Otherwise, `e` is part of the answer.

This should be enough for your case:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct edge {
    int u, v, w;
    edge(){}
    edge(int up, int vp, int wp){u = up; v = vp; w = wp;}
    void print(){ cout<<"("<<u<<", "<<v<<")"<<endl; }
    bool operator<(const edge& rhs) const {return w < rhs.w;}
};

vector<edge> E;             //edge set
priority_queue<edge> pq;
vector<edge> ans;
int grade[5] = {3, 3, 2, 2, 2};

int main(){

    E.push_back(edge(0, 2, 1)); E.push_back(edge(0, 3, 1)); E.push_back(edge(0, 4, 4));
    E.push_back(edge(1, 2, 5)); E.push_back(edge(1, 3, 2)); E.push_back(edge(1, 4, 0));
    for(int i = 0; i < E.size(); i++) pq.push(E[i]);

    while(!pq.empty()){
        edge e = pq.top();
        if(grade[e.u] > 1 && grade[e.v] > 1){
            grade[e.u]--; grade[e.v]--;
        }
        else ans.push_back(e);
        pq.pop();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) ans[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

**Complexity: O(E lg(E))**.

Comment: I believe this is what I was (inappropriately, perhaps) calling "greedy". That is, in a situation where **all** elements of B are closest to one element of A, only that element of A will be assigned. I need edges for all elements, even if it means accepting a greater overall cost.

Comment: Just modified the answer to a different greedy approach to avoid leaving isolated nodes in the graph.

Comment: The idea isn't adding nodes in the answer, but instead, consider all nodes as the initial answer and start removing the nodes with biggest weights that can be removed without leaving unconnected nodes.

Comment: Not a personal attack, but man, why is C++ code always so stylistically cryptic. Why call a variable `E`? You could have just called it `edge_set`, removing the need for that comment. So many parts here are "suffocating", like `while(!pq.empty()){`. Conside `wihle (!pg.empty()) {`

Comment: It's just common for me to call the set of edges of a graph `E`. About "suffocating" code, I noticed that people have a bias to prefer shorter code instead of very organized but big code, so I try to mix something that is small but still understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is "minimum weighted bipartite matching" (although searching for " maximum weighted bipartite matching" would also be relevant, it's just the opposite)

Comment: I'm going to mark @Daniel's answer as correct, but I'll bump up your answer's "useful" count. Thanks again.